# ASP.NET wizard control navigates twice after changing ActiveStepIndex

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, viewstate

I have an application with a bunch of wizards. In one of the wizards when the user is on the last step some code runs in the code-behind to check the form's values so far. If there is an issue with one of the values, a yes/no pop-up gets displayed (user control). If the user clicks on yes, they get taken to the step with the incorrect values via changing `ActiveStepIndex` in the code-behind.

This works locally and on my build server, the step gets changed, navigation happens and all is well. But on my QA server another post-back is triggered immediately afterwards that navigates to the previous step again.

Through debugging I have found that the AJAX post-back is triggered from the `_domReady` function of `MicrosoftAjax.js`. Apparently it's supposed to check for browser navigation events or some such. In my case the state comparison that gets done in the `_navigate` function results in the second post-back happening because the two states are different. The new state is different from the old state, which gets set by the `ScriptManager` [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/UI/ScriptManager.cs,2011).

```
function Sys$_Application$_navigate(entry) {
    this._ensureHistory();
    var state = this._deserializeState(entry);

    if (this._uniqueId) {
        var oldServerEntry = this._state.__s || '';
        var newServerEntry = state.__s || '';
        if (newServerEntry !== oldServerEntry) {
            this._updateHiddenField(newServerEntry);
            __doPostBack(this._uniqueId, newServerEntry);
            this._state = state;
            return;
        }
    }
    this._setState(entry);
    this._state = state;
    this._raiseNavigate();
}
```

Any idea why the server states might be different in one environment but not the other? It happens in all browsers, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out the warning pop-up was outside the wizard's update panel. After I moved it inside the update panel, the view states were in sync and no extra post-back was made.

I still don't understand why it worked fine locally, though.